# Matplotlib plot iterating plot features

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am writing a Python script that will cycle through every ASCII file in a directory and output an individual plot of the data contained with said file. Moreover, it finds the best curve-fitting parameters and outputs those into one combined text file.

The text output works perfectly, but the plot output does not. On the first iteration, it works fine, but after that, it iterates the plot features. For example, on the third iteration of `for filename in os.listdir(directory)`, the draws three legend labels, three fit curves, and each data point three times. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith((".lc", ".lc1")):
        wf = directory + "/" + filename
        try:
            # get the data
            time, flux = getData(wf, nheader)

            # fit the data
            popt_sine, err_sine = sineFit(time, flux)
            popt_exp, err_exp = expFit(time, flux)

            # plot/save the data
            plotData(filename, time, flux, popt_sine, popt_exp)

            # output the data
            output = outputData(popt_sine, err_sine, popt_exp, err_exp)
            print(output)
        except StopIteration:
            raise IOError("End of File Error")
```

where I have defined the function plotData as:

```
def plotData(filename, time, flux, popt_sine, popt_exp):
    t = np.linspace(time[0], time[len(time)-1], 10000)

    # Sine plot
    A = popt_sine[0]
    B = popt_sine[1]
    C = popt_sine[2]
    D = popt_sine[3]
    plt.plot(t, sine(t, A, B, C, D), "r", label="Sine Fit")

    # Exponential plot
    E = popt_exp[0]
    F = popt_exp[1]
    G = popt_exp[2]
    H = popt_exp[3]
    #plt.plot(t, exponential(t, E, F, G, H), label='Exponential Fit')

    # Raw plot
    plt.plot(time, flux, "ko", label = "Data")

    # Plot config.
    plt.xlabel("Time (sec)")
    plt.ylabel("Flux")
    plt.title("Mean Normalized Flux vs. Time (" + filename + ")")
    plt.legend(loc='best')

    # save plot
    if filename.endswith(".lc"):
        plt.savefig(filename[:-3] + ".jpg")
    elif filename.endswith(".lc1"):
        plt.savefig(filename[:-4] + ".jpg")
    else:
        raise ValueError("Incorrect input file type")
    #plt.show()
```

One interesting thing I noticed: if I do `plt.show()` rather than trying to save the plot, wherein I view and exit each plot separately, each plot will be correct.

Comment: I think that you just need to make a new figure with `plt.figure()` in each iteration of your loop (or within your "plotData" function)

Comment: That worked. Thanks for the help.